# Как добавить id юзера в href тег a? php

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста как добавить айдишник юзера в тег a?

```html
//Получение id юзера
$user = $this->userRepository->findUserByUsername($user);
$userId = $user->getId();

//имеется вот такой preg_replace который находит нужный текст и оборачивает каждое найденное значение в тег а
preg_replace($regex, '<a href="#">$1</a>', $sourceText)

// изначальный текст
$sourceText = text @user text text text @user2, @user3 text @user4 @user5!! text

// Оборачивание найденного значения в тег a
<a href="#">$1</a>

// регулярка которая ищет нужные значения
$regex = #(@\w+)#
```

сейчас на выходе получается вот так

```html
text <a href="#">@user</a> text text text <a href="#">@user2</a>, <a href="#">@user3</a> text <a href="#">@user4</a> <a href="#">@user5</a>!! text
```

```
необходимо чтобы было вот так
```

```html
text <a href="site.com/prof/$userId">@user</a> text text text <a href="site.com/prof/$userId">@user2</a>, <a href="site.com/prof/$userId">@user3</a> text <a href="site.com/prof/$userId">@user4</a> <a href="site.com/prof/$userId">@user5</a>!! text
```

Comment: и что такое у вас `$userId` ?

Comment: вначале просто потренеруйся конкатинацию $userId='aaa';
echo '<a href="site.com/prof/'.$userId.'">fdsf</a>';

Comment: Можете точно написать, что за $user и что должно получится -на выходите. Как я понимаю @ user2, @ user3 это разные пользователи и должны вести на разные адреса

Comment: @teran у каждого юзера свой айдишник. Который ищется в репе по логину

Comment: @bloom по синтаксису разберусь, суть про основное решение

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов каждый юзер упомянутый в итоге должен обернуться в тег а с сылкой на профиль юзера. Каждый юзер ищется в бд по логину и потом у юзера берется id который должен в href подставится

Answer (score 0):

не до конца понял чего надо получить в итоге.
смею предположить что надо заменить @user на ссылку.

```
$sourceText = "this is a @user link";
 $pattern = '/@(\S+)/i';
 $replace = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
 echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $sourceText);
```

Comment: описал задачу немного по другому по проще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078082/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-href-%d0%bd%d0%b0-id-%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-php

Comment: и все же потрясающая способность задавать вопросы чтобы ничего не понять. так? $replace = '<a href="http://url?user=$userID">@$1</a>';

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

interface UserRepoInterface
{
  public function findUserByUsername($userName): ?User;
}

class User
{
  private $id;

  public function __construct($id)
  {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }
}

class UserRepoMock implements UserRepoInterface
{
  private $db;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->db = [
      'user'  => new User(1),
      'user2' => new User(2),
      'user3' => new User(3),
      'user4' => new User(4),
      'foo'   => new User(125),
    ];
  }

  public function findUserByUsername($userName): ?User
  {
    return $this->db[$userName] ?? null;
  }
}


class LinkGenerator
{
  private $userRepository;
  private $uri;

  public function __construct($uri, UserRepoInterface $userRepo)
  {
    $this->userRepository = $userRepo;
    $this->uri            = $uri;
  }

  public function generateFrom($sourceText, $regex, $replacement)
  {

    $matches      = [];
    $replacements = [];
    $needles      = [];
    $escape       = chr(1);
    // получаем список юзверей по паттерну
    preg_match_all($regex, $sourceText, $matches);
    // экранируем юзверей в исходной строке
    $sourceText = preg_replace($regex, implode([$escape, '$1', $escape]), $sourceText);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
      $user = $this->userRepository->findUserByUsername(substr($match, 1));;
      if ($user) {
        $userId         = $user->getId();
        // если нашли юзверя, формируем замену
        $replacements[] = str_replace(['#', '$1'], [$this->uri . $userId, $match], $replacement);
      } else {
        // если не нашли, кладем как есть
        $replacements[] = $match;
      }
      // будем искать экранированые имена, т.к. в замене имя тоже присутствует 
      $needles[] = implode([$escape, $match, $escape]);
    }

    return str_replace($needles, $replacements, $sourceText);
  }

}

$generator   = new LinkGenerator('site.com/prof/', new UserRepoMock());
$regex       = '#(@\w+)#';
$sourceText  = 'text @user text text text @user2, @user3 text @user4 @user5!! text @foo';
$replacement = '<a href="#">$1</a>';
echo $generator->generateFrom($sourceText, $regex, $replacement);
```

ЗЫ. Вероятно можно проще, думать лень.